# Creating Script to get user specific detail from AD

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to get a specific attribute from a user details using interactive powershell
I used the below lines but with no luck

```
$User = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the user Initials'
$Mobile = Get-ADuser -Filter {initials -eq "$User"} -Properties * | Select-Object mobile
Write-Host "Phone Number is '$Mobile'"
```

Comment: Start debugging by finding out if the filter works. That is, does `get-aduser -filter {initials -eq "$user"}` return anything? If it does, examine if `mobile` property is populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the way you coded the filter. I changed some other things as well. This works:

```
$User = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the user Initials'
$oUser = Get-ADuser -Filter "initials -eq '$User'" -Properties mobile 

Write-Host "Phone Number is $($oUser.mobile)"
```

Comment: if i want to make it looping how to do it

Comment: Well, that sounds like a general programming question. I suggest you study some of the many sources that exist on the internet This is a good start: https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/PowerShell/Loops  Try things yourself and learn. If you encounter problems, present your code here and ask for help on **your** code.